# how do I transform a DataFrame in pandas with a function applied to many slices in each row?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a function f to many slices within each row of a pandas DataFrame.
For example, DataFrame df would look as such:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.round(np.random.normal(size=(2,49)), 2))
```

So, I have a dataframe of 2 rows by 49 columns, and my function needs to be applied to every consequent slice of 7 data points in both rows, and so that the resulting dataframe looks identical to the input dataframe.

I was doing it as such:

```
df1=df.copy()
df1.T[:7], df1.T[7:14], df1.T[14:21],..., df1.T[43:50] = f(df.T.iloc[:7,:]), f(df.T.iloc[7:14,:]),..., f(df.T.iloc[43:50,:])
```

As you can see that's a whole lot of redundant code.. so I would like to create a loop or something so that it applies the function to every 7 subsequent data point... 
I have no idea how to approach this. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

I thought I could maybe use a transform function for this, but in the pandas documentation I can only see that applied to a dataframe that has been grouped and not on slices of the data....

Hopefully this is clear.. let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: If you're applying the same function to all of the groups, why not just apply it to the whole dataframe? does the function aggregate the values in some why? (all of these questions I have could be avoided if you simply included some example output that you would like to see)

Comment: First, I want to say that I've studied basic python and had an intro into pandas, but I'm overwhelmed by pandas a bit.. So, I found it hard for me to breakdown my eventual goals into one question, so I thought it made more sense to go in little steps and build on top of each other to finally get the full picture, but I was worried that it would seem like I'm repeating myself. But yes, one of the things I want to do I guess is transform matrices into same-size output matrices, not so much aggregating- but mostly I need to apply functions to slices of the rows of my input matrix..

Comment: So then it's not at all clear why this has to be broken up into groups if you're using the same function. In other words, you can operate on a column as if it was a single value, but the operation will be vectorized. try out: `df['f(A)'] = f(df['A'])`

Comment: it'll take me a bit to digest your answer, but this is very useful info for me at this point. I do want eventually be fluent in applying these things as such, but didn't know how to step into the whole indexing and grouping with pandas. Delicate balancing between learning code and getting my project done...I'll be trying to apply your answer to my needs. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid redundant code you can just do a loop like this:

```
STEP = 7
for i in range(0,len(df),STEP):
    df1.T[i:i+STEP] = f(df1.T[i:i+STEP]) # could also do an apply here somehow, depending on what you want to do
```

Answer (score 1):

### Don't Repeat Yourself

You don't provide any examples of your desired output, so here's my best guess at what you want...

If your data are lumped into groups of seven, the you need to come up with a way to label them as such.

If other words, you with want to work with arbitrary arrays, use numpy. If you want to work with labeled, meaningful data and it's associated metadata, then use pandas.

Also, pandas works more efficiently when operating (and displaying!) row-wise data. So that mean store data long (49x2), not wide (2x49)

Here's an example of what I mean. I have the same 49x2 random array, but assigned grouping labels to the rows ahead of time.

Let's yeah you're reading in some wide-ish data as following:

```
import pandas
import numpy
from io import StringIO # python 3
# from StringIO import StringIO # python 2

datafile = StringIO("""\
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9
1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9
2.0,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9
""")
df = pandas.read_csv(datafile)
print(df)

   A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
0  0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
1  1  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9
2  2  2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9
```

You could add a cluster value to the columns, like so:

```
cluster_size = 3
col_vals = []
for n, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    cluster = int(n/cluster_size)
    col_vals.append((cluster, col))

df.columns = pandas.Index(col_vals)
print(df)


   0              1              2              3
   A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
0  0  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
1  1  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9
2  2  2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9
```

By default, the `groupby` method tries to group rows, but you can group columns (I just fogured this out), by passing `axis=1` when you create the object. So the sum of each cluster of columns for each row is as follows:

```
df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()

     0    1    2    3
0  0.3  1.2  2.1  0.9
1  3.3  4.2  5.1  1.9
2  6.3  7.2  8.1  2.9
```

### But again, if all you're doing is more "global" operations, there's no need to any of this.

#### In-place column cluster operation

```
df[0] *= 5
print(df)
    0              1              2              3
    A     B   C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
0   0   2.5   5  0.3  0.4  0.5  0.6  0.7  0.8  0.9
1  25  27.5  30  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9
2  50  52.5  55  2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9
```

---

#### In-place row operation

```
df.T[0] += 20

    0               1                 2                 3
    A     B   C     D     E     F     G     H     I     J
0  20  22.5  25  20.3  20.4  20.5  20.6  20.7  20.8  20.9
1  25  27.5  30   1.3   1.4   1.5   1.6   1.7   1.8   1.9
2  50  52.5  55   2.3   2.4   2.5   2.6   2.7   2.8   2.9
```

---

#### Operate on the entire dataframe at once

```
def myFunc(x):
    return 5 + x**2

myFunc(df)

      0                      1                       2                       3
      A        B     C       D       E       F       G       H       I       J
0   405   511.25   630  417.09  421.16  425.25  429.36  433.49  437.64  441.81
1   630   761.25   905    6.69    6.96    7.25    7.56    7.89    8.24    8.61
2  2505  2761.25  3030   10.29   10.76   11.25   11.76   12.29   12.84   13.41
```

Comment: Read my data from file and trying to apply indexes to the (43,49) df. I put all my indexes as a list of tuples (idx_tuple) and then created multi-index by `index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(idx_tuple, names=['nr', 'date_sample', 'month', 'conc', 'time'])`. Now tried to update my df as such:
`df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = df, index=index, columns = range(43)` The indexing looks good, but my data are all converted to NaNs.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @oaklander114 absolutely impossible to say without seeing some of your data.

Comment: For example, the below code turns the data point into NaNs `df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(np.random.normal(size=(5,6)), 2))`
`ind1 = ['one','two','three', 'four', 'five']`
`ind2 = ['15','15','15','30','30']`
`ind = [ind1,ind2]`
`df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, index = ind)`

I also tried `df.reindex(index=ind)`

Comment: @oaklander114 Also, don't put code in comments -- edit your question to reflect what you've tried. And I'm going to keep repeating this until you actually do it: *add and example of your desired output to your question* -- it allows us to skip so many iteration while we figure out what your actually means.

Comment: Problem is that this question has side-tracked into something else. If i update the question it becomes of a totally different nature.. not better to open a new question then? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65050/discussion-between-oaklander114-and-paul-h).